# strange mouse' cursor behavior regardless of usb port and mouse

Tags: macos, mission-control, mouse

a very strange problem has been bothering me for long time, since when I started to use this mac which is not mine.

Often, while I'm moving the mouse the cursor suddenly begin to move randomly. This happens with strange time intervals. Maybe it happens especially when I try to move a window dragging it from the title bar (or this is just my perception, do to the frustration of not succeeding in moving a window where I want it to be!).

Anyway.....

1. The first try was to change the mouse (a magic mouse) with another one (logitech). The problem persisted.
2. Then I supposed the reason to be the keyboard's usb port used to connect the mouse, so I connected the mouse directly to the mac. Still the same problem was present.
3. In the end I noticed an even stranger behavior: when the cursor starts to randomly and suddenly jump all around the monitor (for instance when I'm trying to drag a window around), if I go in mission control (by the mouse itself or by keyboard), the cursor returns to work properly.

This problem is very frustrating and, as already said, it presents very often, regardless of the mouse and of the usb port it's connected to. And this keeps me from buying one.

Comment: Perhaps the texture of whatever surface you have the mouse on is throwing it off? Usually if that happens to me, the mouse movement is stunted, not random, but if you are on something like a wooden desk, maybe the color of the grain (or whatever) is messing with the mice (assuming they're both optical).

Comment: I'll try to put the mouse on a book or whatever. Anyway this would not explain why going in mission control solves the problem as long as I remain in mission control.

Comment: Gotcha...I assumed, I guess, that if you were triggering mission control, you were stopping your mouse motion, and that might've been causing the problem to stop. It was the first thing that popped into my head, but it sounds like that's probably not it.

Comment: No, I just kept the mouse in movement when going in/out mission control. It's so strage!